# Ошибка при добавлении стандартного виджета товаров WooCommerce в пост блога

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую код, который изменяет текст и стиль кнопки «Добавить в корзину» для товара, добавленного в корзину.

```
/* Меняем текст кнопки добавления в корзину для каталога и категорий */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'new_products_button_text', 20, 2 );
 
function new_products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
 
    if( 
       $product->is_type( 'simple' )
       && $product->is_purchasable()
       && $product->is_in_stock()
       && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
    ) { 
        $text = 'В корзине'; 
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}

/* Меняем текст кнопки добавления в корзину для страницы товара */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'new_single_product_button_text' );
 
function new_single_product_button_text( $text ) {
 
    if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        $text = 'В корзине';
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
function action_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var selector = '.add_to_cart_text:contains("В корзине")';           
            
            // Selector contains specific text
            if ( $( selector ).length > 0 ) {
                $( selector ).addClass( 'product-is-added' );
            } else {
                $( selector ).removeClass( 'product-is-added' );            
            }
            
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_button_text_js_script' );
function ajax_button_text_js_script() {
    $text = __('В корзине', 'woocommerce');
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>',      $this;

            $(document.body).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart', function(event){
                $this = $(this); // Get button jQuery Object and set it in a variable
            });

            $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function(event,b,data){
                var buttonText = '<span class="add_to_cart_text product-is-added">'+text+'</span><i class="cart-icon pe-7s-cart"></i>';

                // Change inner button html (with text) and Change "data-tip" attribute value
                $this.html(buttonText).attr('data-tip',text);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Сам код работает корректно, но вот в блогах возникла проблема. При создании постов блога, я использую визуальный редактор WPBakery Page Builder. Также в посты блога добавляю стандартный WooCommerce виджет с товарами.

При публикации или сохранении поста cо стандартным виджетом WooCommerce, я получаю критическую ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find_product_in_cart() on null in /public_html/wp-content/themes/functions.php:703
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): new_products_button_text('\xD0\x92 \xD0\xBA\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xB7\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBD...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))
#1 /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters('\xD0\x92 \xD0\xBA\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xB7\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBD...', Array)
#2 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-simple.php(62): apply_filters('woocommerce_pro...', '\xD0\x92 \xD0\xBA\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xB7\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBD...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))
#3 /public_html/wp-content/themes/cores/nasa-woo-functions.php(393): WC_Product_Simple->add_to_cart_text()
#4 /public_html/wp-content/themes/cores/nasa-woo- in /public_html/wp-content/themes/functions.php on line 703

Без виджета товаров, пост публикуется без проблем.

703-я строка, это часть показанного выше кода:

```
&& WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: WC()->cart видимо null

Comment: Я вижу, что он отдает null. Но как это исправить? Почему при добавлении товаров такой проблемы нет? Ошибка только в блогах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это приходит потому что корзина не инитится в админ панели так как она не нужна в этом месте. Чтобы решить эту проблему у вас есть два варианта

1. Не работать с фильтрами в админ панели

   ```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'new_products_button_text', 20, 2 );

   function new_products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
       if ( is_admin() ) {
           return $text;
       }

       if(
         $product->is_type( 'simple' )
         && $product->is_purchasable()
         && $product->is_in_stock()
         && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
       ) {
           $text = 'В корзине';
       }

       return $text;
   }

   add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'new_single_product_button_text' );

   function new_single_product_button_text( $text ) {
       if ( is_admin() ) {
           return $text;
       }

       if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
           $text = 'В корзине';
       }

       return $text;
   }
   ```
2. Загрузить корзину принудительно

   ```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'new_products_button_text', 20, 2 );

   function new_products_button_text( $text, $product ) {

       if ( is_admin() && is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
           wc_load_cart();
       }

       if(
         $product->is_type( 'simple' )
         && $product->is_purchasable()
         && $product->is_in_stock()
         && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
       ) {
           $text = 'В корзине';
       }

       return $text;

   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Второй вариант работает. Я тоже подумал о корзине и вы очень в этом помогли!